# Group by with multiple cases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It is possible to put multiple `Group By` clauses in the same `Select`? I'm doing a store procedure and want to return the value of a range of days. If this range of days surpass a quantity, then I want to `group by` the months, and if this months return a qunatity greater than a year, I want to return the names of the years.

The data is just the current ID of the table, the ID of another table with multiple dates values, all dates are unique withing the other table ID.

I just want to return all the dates of that external table summaries.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(D.VALUE) SUM_VALUE,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(month,MIN(D.DATE_FIELD),MAX(D.DATE_FIELD)) > 12 THEN YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
        WHEN DATEDIFF(week,MIN(D.DATE_FIELD),MAX(D.DATE_FIELD)) > 12 THEN DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD) + ' ' + YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
        ELSE DATEPART(DAY, D.DATE_FIELD) + ' ' + DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD) + ' ' + YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
    END AS NAME

    FROM VALUE_DATE_TABLE D
    WHERE D.ANOTHER_TABLE_ID = @some_ID
    GROUP BY (
            YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD) 
        HAVING
            DATEDIFF(month,MIN(D.DATE_FIELD),MAX(D.DATE_FIELD)) > 12
        OR
             DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD), YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
        HAVING 
            DATEDIFF(week,MIN(D.DATE_FIELD),MAX(D.DATE_FIELD)) > 12
        OR 
            DATEPART(DAY, D.DATE_FIELD), DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD), YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD))
```

I'm trying to do the multiple `groups by`.

The idea would be doing these 3 groups by in the select

```
Group by YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
Group by DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD), YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
Group by DATEPART(DAY, D.DATE_FIELD), DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD), YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
```

Comment: I don't fully follow your question, but you can't have multiple `GROUP BY` statements in a single select.  What you _can_ do would be to use sum as an analytic function three times, each with its own particular partition.

Comment: That actually looks like what you might be after is `WITH ROLLUP`.

Comment: What I want to do is a condition of the group by, if possible, depending on the amounts of dates returned. If more than 12 days, return months, if more than 12 months return years. I hope this clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS()`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(D.VALUE) SUM_VALUE,
  CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(month,MIN(D.DATE_FIELD),MAX(D.DATE_FIELD)) > 12 
    THEN YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
    WHEN DATEDIFF(week,MIN(D.DATE_FIELD),MAX(D.DATE_FIELD)) > 12 
    THEN DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD) + ' ' + YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
    ELSE DATEPART(DAY, D.DATE_FIELD) + ' ' + DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD) 
         + ' ' + YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD)
    END AS NAME
FROM VALUE_DATE_TABLE D
WHERE D.ANOTHER_TABLE_ID = @some_ID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD))
  ,(DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD), YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD))
  ,(DATEPART(DAY, D.DATE_FIELD), DATEPART(WK, D.DATE_FIELD), YEAR(D.DATE_FIELD))
 );
```

**EDIT:**

> *This seens the right way, but how do I tell the sql which grouping set I'm using*

You could use [`GROUPING_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-id-transact-sql):

> **Is a function that computes the level of grouping. GROUPING_ID can be used only in the SELECT  list, HAVING, or ORDER BY clauses when GROUP BY is specified.**

Comment: This seens the right way, but how do I tell the sql which grouping set I'm using?

Comment: I have tested this with my code,it returns the table splited in the differents Group By, shamfully, is not possible (or not that I know) tell a condition to avoid showing one group or the other in certains occasions, it will always return all with the other values in null, which I'm not interested in.

Comment: I solve the problem using this and restricting the select better in linq. Thanks for the help.